# Correct WFS transaction response

Tags: qgis, wfs, wfs-t

I am trying to implement a transactional WFS. For now, I am only focusing on supporting the insert operation.

I have been able to successfully parse the insert XML posted by QGIS to my endpoint, but I am unable to create an output XML document to signal QGIS that the operation was successful. QGIS throws `"Unhandled response: TransactionResponse"` upon receiving my response. I have based the response schema on [OGC's documentation](https://www.ogc.org/standards/wfs) and currently don't see a mismatch.

Below is an example input XML posted by QGIS.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Transaction xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/wfs" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation=" http://localhost:7554/?SERVICE=WFS&amp;REQUEST=DescribeFeatureType&amp;VERSION=1.0.0&amp;TYPENAME=ExampleLayerName" version="1.0.0" service="WFS">
    <Insert>
        <ExampleLayerName>
            <geom>
                <gml:Polygon srsName="EPSG:4326">
                    <gml:outerBoundaryIs>
                        <gml:LinearRing>
                            <gml:coordinates ts=" " cs=",">-67.41570626436781311,-20.93247614942528756 -67.44912965517241332,-21.50067379310344862 -66.94777879310343849,-20.96589954022988422 -67.41570626436781311,-20.93247614942528756</gml:coordinates>
                        </gml:LinearRing>
                    </gml:outerBoundaryIs>
                </gml:Polygon>
            </geom>
        </Distritos>
    </Insert>
</Transaction>
```

Below is the generated response XML by my endpoint.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<wfs:TransactionResponse xmlns:wfs="http://www.opengis.net/wfs/2.0" xmlns:fes="http://www.opengis.net/fes/2.0"
    xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml/3.2" xmlns:ows="http://www.opengis.net/ows/1.1"
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="2.0.0"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/wfs/2.0 http://localhost:8080/geoserver/schemas/wfs/2.0/wfs.xsd">
    <wfs:TransactionSummary>
        <wfs:totalInserted>1</wfs:totalInserted>
        <wfs:totalUpdated>0</wfs:totalUpdated>
        <wfs:totalReplaced>0</wfs:totalReplaced>
        <wfs:totalDeleted>0</wfs:totalDeleted>
    </wfs:TransactionSummary>
    <wfs:InsertResults>
        <wfs:Feature>
            <fes:ResourceId rid="0" />
        </wfs:Feature>
    </wfs:InsertResults>
</wfs:TransactionResponse>
```

EDIT:

Part of the `GetCapabilities` document:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<wfs:WFS_Capabilities xmlns:wfs="http://www.opengis.net/wfs/2.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/wfs/2.0" xmlns:ows="http://www.opengis.net/ows/1.1" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml/3.2" xmlns:fes="http://www.opengis.net/fes/2.0" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" version="2.0.0" updateSequence="1913">
    <ows:ServiceIdentification>
        <ows:Title>My WFS</ows:Title>
        <ows:Abstract>My WFS</ows:Abstract>
        <ows:ServiceType>WFS</ows:ServiceType>
        <ows:ServiceTypeVersion>2.0.0</ows:ServiceTypeVersion>
    </ows:ServiceIdentification>
    <ows:OperationsMetadata>
        <ows:Operation name="Transaction">
            <ows:DCP>
                <ows:HTTP>
                    <ows:Get xlink:href="http://localhost:7554/v1/wfs/"/>
                    <ows:Post xlink:href="http://localhost:7554/v1/wfs/"/>
                </ows:HTTP>
            </ows:DCP>
            <ows:Parameter name="inputFormat">
                <ows:AllowedValues>
                    <ows:Value>application/gml+xml; version=3.2</ows:Value>
                </ows:AllowedValues>
            </ows:Parameter>
            <ows:Parameter name="AcceptVersions">
                <ows:AllowedValues>
                    <ows:Value>2.0.0</ows:Value>
                </ows:AllowedValues>
            </ows:Parameter>
        </ows:Operation>
    </ows:OperationsMetadata>
</wfs:WFS_Capabilities>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that QGIS as of version 3.14.0-Pi, does not support WFS-T 2.0.0 yet ([Source](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/34608)). Even though my WFS advertised to support only WFS 2.0.0, QGIS simply attempts to use WFS 1.0.0.

After I changed my response to a WFS 1.0.0 compliant response ([Specification](http://file:///home/minghai/Downloads/02-058_Web_Feature_Service_WFS.pdf)), QGIS stopped throwing errors after posting the transaction.

Below is an example response my endpoint created for WFS 1.0.0:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<wfs:WFS_TransactionResponse version="1.0.0" xmlns:wfs="http://www.opengis.net/wfs"
    xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
    <wfs:TransactionResult>
        <wfs:Status>
            <wfs:SUCCESS />
        </wfs:Status>
    </wfs:TransactionResult>
    <wfs:InsertResult>
        <ogc:FeatureId fid="62f617c3-22f0-40a7-9f64-9fd8b0ff11c2" />
    </wfs:InsertResult>
</wfs:WFS_TransactionResponse>
```

Thanks to [Ian Turton](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/79/ian-turton) and [user30184](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/30184/user30184) for their observations.

Answer (score 4):

It's hard to be sure but it looks like QGIS is sending a version 1.0.0 request and you are responding with a version 2.0 response. I would expect QGIS to become confused when you do that.

You need to negotiate the version with the client when it first requests the getcapabilities document.

> 6.2.4        Version number negotiation
>
> An OWS Client may negotiate with a Service Instance to determine a mutually agreeable
> specification version.  Negotiation is performed using the
> GetCapabilities operation [sec.  13] according to the following rules.
>
> All Capabilities XML must include a protocol version number.  In
> response to a GetCapabilities request containing a version number, a
> web feature service  must either respond with output that conforms to
> that version of the specification, or negotiate a mutually agreeable
> version if the requested version is not implemented on the server.  If
> no version number is specified in the request, the server must respond
> with the highest version it understands and label the response
> accordingly.
>
> Version number negotiation occurs as follows:
>
> If the server implements the requested version number, the server must
> send that version. If the client request is for an unknown version
> greater than the lowest version that the server understands, the
> server must send the highest version less than the requested version.
> If the client request is for a version lower than any of those known
> to the server, then the server must send the lowest version it knows.
> If the client does not understand the new version number sent by the
> server, it may either cease communicating with the server or send a
> new request with a new version number that the client does understand,
> but which is less than that sent by the server (if the server had
> responded with a lower version). If the server had responded with a
> higher version (because the request was for a version lower than any
> known to the server), and the client does not understand the proposed
> higher version, then the client may send a new request with a version
> number higher than that sent by the server. The process is repeated
> until a mutually understood version is reached, or until the client
> determines that it will not or cannot communicate with that particular
> server.
>
> Example 1:   Server understands versions 1, 2, 4, 5 and 8.  Client
> understands versions 1, 3, 4, 6, and 7.  Client requests version 7.
> Server responds with version 5.  Client requests version 4.  Server
> responds with version 4, which the client understands, and the
> negotiation ends successfully.
>
> Example 2:   Server understands versions 4, 5 and 8.  Client
> understands version 3.  Client requests version 3.  Server responds
> with version 4.  Client does not understand that version or any higher
> version, so negotiation fails and client ceases communication with
> that server.

Comment: I see that the input document from QGIS indeed states WFS version 1.0.0. I added part of my GetCapabilities document in my question.

As far as I know, the document negotiates for only 2.0.0, but QGIS still somehow puts 1.0.0 in. Maybe my GetCapabilities document is incorrect?

Comment: QGIS should only pick a version listed in your capabilities document

Comment: It may be that QGIS can do transactions only with WFS 1.0.0 so it might be best to stay with that all the time. But I just found a document that can be useful  https://gist.github.com/SKalt/0f4b757209687331c8a1d40aecbf69f9.

Comment: It seems that QGIS indeed only supports WFS-T 1.0.0. [Source](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/34608). I am going to create a WFS-T 1.0.0 response and see if that works.

Comment: I just did this and QGIS seems to find my response satisfactory. Thanks everyone for your help!